# У меня есть список с элементами. Могу ли я прислать их пользователю Telegram одним сообщения и как? Библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI (telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

У меня есть список, который я выводил в консоль с помощю for. Думал так можно и с сообщениями...

```
for game in final_list:
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Назва гри - ', game['gameName'])
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'мін. Кількість гравців - ', game['minPlayersNumber'])
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Наявність інвентаря - ', game['inventory'])
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Місце для гри - ', game['location'])
```

Но так нельзя(

P.S. В консоль выводил так -

```
for game in final_list:
    print('Назва гри - ', game['gameName'])
    print('мін. Кількість гравців', game['minPlayersNumber'])
    print('Наявність інвентаря - ', game['inventory'])
    print('Місце для гри - ', game['location'], '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно формировать весь текст сообщения заранее

```
msg = ''
for game in final_list:
    msg += f'Назва гри - {game["gameName"]}\n' \
           f'мін. Кількість гравців {game["minPlayersNumber"]}\n ' \
           f'Наявність інвентаря - {game["inventory"]}\n' \
           f'Місце для гри - {game["location"]}\n\n'
bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, msg)
```

Comment: Не помогло( Если что вот сылка на [код](https://nekobin.com/baxutigeri)

Comment: @HyTacker поправил ответ, но нужно еще учесть что в телеграмме сообщение ограничено кол-вом символов

Comment: всё равно ничего не отправляет((

Comment: попробуйте сделать принт `final_list` перед циклом, есть мнение что он либо пустой либо бот вообще не доходит до этой функции

Comment: а как боту отослать final_list? через bot.send_message не выходит.

Comment: @HyTacker сделайте просто `print(final_list)` и посмотрите что внутри. Принт сделайте перед циклом

Comment: спасибо, помогло) в final_list просто ничего не передавалось